# c# - Richtextbox.text throws stackoverflow exception adding lines by event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, richtextbox

I'm appending lines to a RickTextbox by a event, i'm using this code.

```
  private void Process(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Mesage(Process), sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;

            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying add new lines to a RichTextbox in C# WinForms, but it throws a StackOverflow exception in this line.

```
 richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
```

e.Data is a string. What should I do to keep adding lines?

Editing

> The process is linked to fluentmigrator process , returning many lines because it is running queries against a database.

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't *return* a stack overflow exception, it *throws* a stack overflow exception.  It's an important distinction.

Comment: To which event is attached the Process function?

Comment: most of the time, a Stack Overflow  exception happens if you have some sort of infinite recursion loop.  I'd have to check and see what `BeginInvoke()` does again, but `BeginInvoke(new Mesage(Process), sender, e);` looks like it might be the culprit.

Comment: Put the code inside of a try...catch so you can see what happens.

Comment: Probably, when you set the Text property of richTextBox1, an event is firing which in turn calls the Process method (possibily indirectly).  That will cause infinite recursion and, therefore, overflow the stack.

Comment: @Auguste I think that StackOverflow exception is one of the few exceptions that you can't try/catch

Comment: I think phoog is correct. What kind of event calls the function? My friends often do the mistake of using the textBox_TextChanged event for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and testing, i changed the code to reduce the number of calls to the function. The Process method is called so many times in such a short time that throws the exception. After change, the error no longer occurs.

```
private void Process(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e){
if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
{
    invoked = true;
    BeginInvoke(new Mensagem(ProcessaMensagem), sender, e);
}
else
{
    try
    {       
        commands.Add(e.Data);
        count++;
        if (count % 5 == 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.Lines = commands.ToArray();
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();

            Application.DoEvents();             
        }       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log logic
    }
}}
```